# MySQL overwrite value with value from another field

Tags: mysql

Here is data set which i have:

```
 user_id     sum_min          sum_max  
----------  ---------------  -----------------
    38        300000.00          300000.00
    38        320000.00          320000.00
    38        340000.00          340000.00
    38        350000.00          350000.00
    38        380000.00          380000.00
    38        380000.00          380000.00
    38        400000.00          400000.00
    38        420000.00          420000.00
    38        450000.00          450000.00
    38        450000.00          450000.00
    38        480000.00          480000.00
    38        480000.00          480000.00
    38        500000.00          500000.00
    38        520000.00          520000.00
```

What i need to do is establish range like value for sum_max is value of sum_min from next record.
Expected result should be:

```
 user_id     sum_min          sum_max  
----------  ---------------  -----------------
    38        300000.00          320000.00
    38        320000.00          340000.00
    38        340000.00          350000.00 
    38        350000.00          380000.00
    38        380000.00          380000.00
    38        380000.00          380000.00
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: how about some actual information that might enable someone to answer your question? At the very least schema design and desired output is mandatory.  It would also be useful to know what you've already tried.  You might know exactly what you're asking but unless you explain it nobody else will

Comment: Question is not clear! Please elaborate the expected output

Comment: Your expected output is same as your table except few rows. How would one understand how did you get this rows without any condition as your user_id is also same

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,user_id     INT NOT NULL
,sum_min      INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,sum_min) VALUES
(    38    ,   30),
(    38    ,    32),
(38        ,34),
(38        ,35),
(38        ,38),
(38        ,38),
(38        ,40),
(38        ,42),
(38        ,45),
(38        ,45),
(38        ,48),
(38        ,48),
(38        ,50),
(38        ,52);

SELECT x.user_id
     , x.sum_min
     , MIN(y.sum_min) sum_max 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND y.sum_min > x.sum_min 
 GROUP 
    BY user_id
     , sum_min;

+---------+---------+---------+
| user_id | sum_min | sum_max |
+---------+---------+---------+
|      38 |      30 |      32 |
|      38 |      32 |      34 |
|      38 |      34 |      35 |
|      38 |      35 |      38 |
|      38 |      38 |      40 |
|      38 |      40 |      42 |
|      38 |      42 |      45 |
|      38 |      45 |      48 |
|      38 |      48 |      50 |
|      38 |      50 |      52 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```